# Phabricator: Source file ManiphestEditAssignCapability.php failed to load

Tags: phabricator

I upgrade Phabricator to the latest commit (11ce459f67a4beb150d442c65f487c744be43fdd) in "stable" branch. (and libphutil,  archanist)

then upgraded the storage, restarted nginx, php-fpm, clear phabricator cache.

Nevertheless it always shows this error

```
Source file "/var/www/phacility/phabricator/src/applications/maniphest/capability/ManiphestEditAssignCapability.php" failed to load.
```

ManiphestEditAssignCapability.php is a file already removed in the stable branch

My system is CentOS 7, running PHP7.1 from REMI repo

Any help is appreciated

Comment: hi there, are you sure you pull the phabricator completely. This look likes a php class map error. When pulling does not work, just delete the whole phbaricator repo and clone it again.

Comment: I very sure that i pull it correctly. checked git log and compared the hashes. I suspect that it is some sort of caches. Could be opcache. Tried to clear by restarting php-fpm but it didn't work.

Comment: I think the php 7.1 may also be the problem. Phabricator supports php 7.2 upwards and PHP 5.6 if I am not mistaken. There were some problem in PHP 7.0/7.1 that brought some errors. Did try another PHP version? Also It could be a problem with Permission...

Comment: Previously I have another service that was also acting weird after I updated it (it is nextcloud). Also similarly suspecting some sort of cache problem.  During that time I don't know the root cause and tried to downgrade from PHP 7.2 to 7.1 and it solved the problem. Must have been somehow certain cache gets cleared. But I cannot find the root cause still.